# Angular 2: Performance issues

Tags: angular, observable

I have an RC6 app that consists of 15 modules with perhaps 5-7 components each.

Each component is a list of something, like users. It also contains a search form in the sidebar where I can post back to the API to get an updated list.

It works, but suffers from bad performance. If I have 100-200 rows, everything runs smoothly, but above that the browser starts allocating more and more memory and the entire app "lags".

I am new to Angular and I'm probably making a very basic mistake. This is a quick look at how I do things in the different components:

I define a new observable above the constructor:

```
somethingList: Observable<any>;
```

I define a subscription above the constructor:

```
somethingListSubscription: Subscription;
```

I use a lifecycle hook to populate the observable via a service layer:

```
ngOnInit() : void {

    this._feedbackService.startLoading();

    this.somethingListSubscription = this._someService.getSomething()
        .subscribe(
            something => this.somethingList = something,
            error => this._feedbackService.displayError(<any>error),
            () => this._feedbackService.stopLoading()
        );

}
```

This is what the service method looks like:

```
getSomething() : Observable<any> {

    var params = "&param=";

    return this._http
            .post(apiUrl + 'Some/Action', params, {withCredentials: true, headers: this.headers})
            .timeoutWith(8000, Observable.defer(() => Observable.throw(this._feedbackService.timeout())))
            .map((response: Response) => response.json().data);

}
```

Then, when a user submits the search form, I do this:

```
onSearchFormSubmit() {

    this._feedbackService.startLoading();

    var searchFor =  {
        name: this.searchForm.value.name,
        type: this.searchForm.value.type,
        count: this.searchForm.value.count
    };

    this.somethingListSubscription = this._someService.standardSearch(searchFor)
        .subscribe(
            something => this.somethingList = something,
            error => this._feedbackService.displayError(<any>error),
            () => this._feedbackService.stopLoading()
        );

}
```

I then unsubscribe using another lifecycle hook:

```
ngOnDestroy() : void {

    if(this.somethingListSubscription != undefined) {
        this.somethingListSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

And finally, in the HTML i use `ngFor` like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let thing of somethingList; let i = index; let l = last">
    <td>{{thing.value1}}</td>
    <td>{{thing.value2}}</td>
    <td>{{thing.value3}} {{l ? incrementCount(i) : ''}}</td>
</tr>
```

When running the app in a browser profiler, I can see the memory increasing all the time.

I am probably making a very basic mistake?

Comment: "I can see the memory increasing all the time." - Does it increase without you doing anything? Are there specific actions that make it increase every time you perform that action?

Comment: It increases for everytime I populate/re-populate the observable list. I have verified that the actual HTTP calls to the back-end goes fast at all times using Fiddler.

Comment: It seems that you either don't unsubscribe from your Observables properly or that you keep references to variables you no longer use. That aside, you should also look into 'virtual scrolling'. I think you are rendering way too large tables.

Comment: Remember that the browser uses some garbage collection algorithm to clean up objects that are no longer referenced, and that they might remain in memory some time after their last reference is removed, so the memory consumption is not necessarily an indication of a memory leak. The question is, does the memory keep increasing even after hours of execution or does it reach some steady state?

Comment: Suggestion, use `trackBy` to tell the framework that DOM doesn't need to be recreated for subsequent ajax calls. I have no experience with it, but documentation says that if you supply a `trackBy` function that gives a unique id to each record, the framework will behave more efficiently when the list is updated in the model.